# How to add "AND" clause to OUTER JOIN in Django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Lets say I have two tables, auth_group and auth_user_group.  They have a simple relationship where auth_user_group has a group_id field which points to the id field in auth_group.  Let's say we wrote this query in raw sql:

```
select *
from auth_group ag
left join auth_user_groups aug
  on ag.id = aug.group_id
  and aug.user_id is null;
```

Edit...

The question would be the same if this were the query:

```
select *
from auth_group ag
left join auth_user_groups aug
  on ag.id = aug.group_id
  and aug.user_id = 1;
```

My goal here is to get every record from the auth_group table and where there is a matching auth_user_groups record it would return that matching record and where it doesn't exist it would return null

How would I do this in Django ORM?

Further info.  Why would I want to do this you ask?  Simple.  I would like to list all of the possible groups that a user could have and I also want to list which ones they currently have.  Sure, I could do this with two separate queries but that is inefficient when I could just do it with one simple query.

Comment: Can you add your models to your question? These look like the models from the built-in auth app and in that case `auth_user_group.user_id` should not be nullable

Comment: you guessed correctly, these are exactly the models from the built-in auth app and the fact that I'm querying for null is irrelevant because the whole point is that there will be auth_groups and no joined auth_user_groups therefore no value.  But if it makes it easier for you to understand just replace the null with a number and the question is the same

Comment: Have you seen [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects)?

Comment: Here's a [good link](https://sophilabs.com/blog/complex-outer-joins-with-django-filteredrelations) with more examples and showing SQL output.

Comment: I did try FilteredRelation but it did not work.  the problem is that in the django auth model setup auth_group does not have a relation with auth_user_groups but rather with auth_groups.  auth_user_group is not something you can target directly as it is only a join table.  Since asking this question, I have given up on my attempt to query it this way and have opted for two separate calls.  I suspect this is not possible in Django ORM